# How to group units without losing custom formation?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

I arrange all my units how I want them, then group them (or vice versa). But when I order them to move forward they all wander off in different directions and reform into the default formation. Kinda makes grouping not much use as I have to place each individual unit where i want it.

How do I get it to group and also remember the formation of the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a custom formation.

The next best solution is either:

- learn and use the provided formations, and/or
- divide a large formation into groupings and manually move each division to hold place in the formation

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use the arrows provided on the bottom left side to move your custom formation forward, backward, and what not.

To go forward, keep button pressed, it will highlight how far they will move, and release mouse button. Then the army will move accordingly.

I will try to find a screen shot and post it if I can.

Answer (score 2):

Custom formations are possible. To create one, arrange the units in the way you want them, then select them and group them ("G" button) - this is done most easily in the preparation phase. The ensuing group will move in the formation it was created in, unless you select one of the template formations to the left. They will only move in formation if you select them as a group, however - if you were to add even one unit to that is not part of the group to the selection, all units will leave formation and advance chaotically, and the same will happen if you use only a part of the group.

You can easily check if the group you've created will move in formation by right clicking and dragging - this will show a silhouette of the placement the units will try to assume if you release the button, and it will, if successful, be the same as the formation you desire.

Comment: I found, grouping them sometimes invalidates custom formation. You can still arrange them in formation you need without grouping them, and then move the forward.

Comment: You need to group all units that you want to have in the formation. Without grouping, you can only use method you suggested, but with it, you can click anywhere, which is more robust and invaluable if you're playing without pause (max difficulty). I haven't ever had a custom formation collapse on me, as long as I group all the units that need to keep formation and move them strictly together (separate move commands and combat rearrange the formation IIRC, but it can easily be rebuilt the same way).